Why am I getting an unstable video connection on Dell Latitude 5440 running Windows 11 (USB-C / DVI) with a Dell U3011 monitor?
I have a Dell U3011 monitor that I'd like to use with my laptop, a Dell Latitude 5440 (OS: Windows 11).
I want to use the whole 2560×1600 resolution and that is not possible via HDMI (tried and failed).
So I bought a PremiumCord USB 3.1 to DVI, 1.8m cable (wasn't cheap).
My experience is that sometimes it works perfectly: I can extend my screen, and I get the full 2560×1600 resolution.
However, it is really unstable: Sometimes the monitor goes black writing "Entering Power Save Mode", while the laptop senses that the monitor is still there, I can move the cursor outside of the laptop screen.
If I turn on and off the monitor, pull off and plug in the cable, switch between the options in Win+P, then it may (or may not) come back.
Sometimes only the monitor remains off but I can move the cursor outside, sometimes the cursor is stick inside the laptop screen, too.
I could not find a pattern that reliably causes it to turn on or off.
I do not have another laptop with USB-C and / or Windows 11; the monitor works well with my other computers through DVI-D and DisplayPort, Windows 10 and Linux.
What can be the cause of this problem? The monitor, the cable, the laptop, Windows 11?
Is there a way to turn off the Power Save Mode on the monitor?

Similar here, only that I had a working setup with a Win10 laptop and HDMI => DVI-D cable, full res, never a problem in years. Then I got a new Win11 laptop, and that exact setup - I just moved the cable over to the new laptop - only has a low resolution. So I bought a USB-C => DisplayPort cable, because the laptop has a USB4/Thunderbolt/DisplayPort port next to the HDMI port. Laptop recognizes the monitor, I can see it in settings - but the U3011 is just DEAD. Black, but it remains on so there is something, but I cannot even get its menu to appear.

There an Windows 11 optional update named "Dell monitor". Try installing it.

@ChanganAuto Thanks, but my computer has always been updated with everything, I even have "Dell Update" running.

I ended up replacing the PremiumCord cable with a Manhattan 152457. It works perfectly, so it must have been a quality issue.
